# Install Laravel in windows xampp, fix "object not found" error

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, xampp, http-status-code-404

I have installed xampp in my system including several projects.

Now I want place my new site to another directory not in htdocs.

My new project is based on laravel.

I edited the http-xampp.conf as following.

```
Alias /newsite "f:/newsite/"
<Directory "f:/newsite">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now it works fine.

http://localhost/newsite

But when I access the sub routes, it occurs object not found error. My laravel site has several routes.

http://localhost/newsite/subroute

```
Object not found!
    The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
    If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

    192.168.0.2
    Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.5.28
```

I really headache. Can you help me?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You might be missing a RewriteRule, does  http://localhost/newsite/index.php/subroute work?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
By the way, what is index.php in your url?
My url is http://localhost/newsite/subroute

And can you guide me your idea about RewriteRule?

Thanks again. Kaloyan